# Before login hook drupal 8

Tags: hook, drupal-8

I am very new to Drupal. Is there a hook on drupal 8 for pre-login ?

I would like to redirect the login information of a user on a web server by URL (web services).

I know that there is the user_login hook, but this one only looks called once the user is connected to the drupal database. I would like to retrieve the step before, so the login and password information

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a hook_form_alter on the login form and add your submit handler before the actual form submit handler. If this doesn't make sense I can post some codes.

```
 /**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  switch ($form_id) {
    case 'user_login_block':
    case 'user_login' :
      array_unshift($form['#submit'], 'custom_login_submit');
      break;
  }
}

/**
 * Custom submit handler
 */
function custom_login_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  //code here
}
```